# Looping Through Array with ngFor Using Next Button

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Somewhat new to Ionic 3 - I'm looking to loop through an array when I use ngFor. I've used the slice method to display one item from the array at a time. I'm looking to display the next item in the array when I click the "Next" button".

```
<div *ngFor="let reference of content | slice:0:1;">
<div> {{reference.item}} </div>
<div> {{reference.image}} </div>
<div> {{reference.field2}} </div>

<button ion button> Next </button>
```

Not sure if ngFor is the best approach or if there is a better alternative. Thank you!

Comment: `ts` code of your button?

Comment: I currently don't have any code - new to angular/ionic - wasn't sure if you could loop through it using one of the ng directives

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to display all data as a list then you don't require ngFor here.
You can just show data by specifying the index which will increment on each next button click.

```
reference:any;
currentIndexToShow:number = 0;

nextButtonClick() {

   this.currentIndexToShow++;
   this.reference = content[currentIndexToShow];

}

<div> {{reference?.item}} </div>
<div> {{reference?.image}} </div>
<div> {{reference?.field2}} </div>
```

Comment: I'm getting an error with your syntax. Also inside the div's - is it suppose to be reference[0].item or do we want to have the ?'s. Thanks @saj

Comment: There were some syntax issue, it is corrected now. The symbol '?' is a null operator. So if the reference is null when we call referece?.item it won't throw exception the result will return as null. In the reference property it is assigning the data from content in the index so no need to do reference[0].

Comment: Hmm - it's not recognizing the "?" next to the reference. Also it gives me a "not defined" error unless I put "this." before the CurrentIndexToShow and the reference.